# Creating Placeholder for mail template in social engine 4

Tags: zend-framework, email, socialengine

SO I was able to add some field to my contact form using the add element code, but I can't seem to figure out how to include the data from these new fields in the email template.

The other fields use place holders liike [sender_email].  I suppose the fields are being posted to somewhere and then the placeholder is used to access that info.

Does anyone know where the placeholders are defined or perhaps an easier way to put the info in the mail template?

Comment: Ahhh, See I posted this after being confused for a couple hours then figured it out literally 5 minutes after posting.  If anyone cares you can assign the placeholders in the HelpController.php file located in the core module.  Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Comment: You should answer your own question below and accept the answer. This helps those that have same problem as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, See I posted this after being confused for a couple hours then figured it out literally 5 minutes after posting. If anyone cares you can assign the placeholders in the HelpController.php file located in the core module. Hopefully this saves someone some time.